# Grouped by counts in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and trying to learn it. We have a df called allyears that has years, gender, names in it.

Something like this:

| name | sex | number | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | M | 1 | 2010 |
| Jane | F | 2 | 2011 |

I want to group the top10 names for a given year with their respective counts. I tried this code, but this is not returning what I am looking for.

```
males = allyears[(allyears.year>2009)&(allyears.sex=='M')]
maleNameCounts = pd.DataFrame(males.groupby(['year', 'name']).count())
maleNameCounts.sort_values('number', ascending=True)
```

How should I be approaching this problem?

Comment: You are using a bitwise `&` instead of `and`

Comment: bitwise is working.
The problem is with the grouping. I dont know if I got this right.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be grouping, then? You might be able to group by years, then sort by count to get the top ten for each group...

Comment: Yes, sir. 
How do we do that?
This is not returning what I want.
maleNameCounts = pd.DataFrame(males.groupby(['year', 'name']).count())
How do I get a dataset like this ?
|Year|Name|Count|

Comment: Quick question, does the number refer to the overall amount of that name or ...?

Comment: No sir. It is the unique id given to the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```
males = allyears[(allyears.year>2009)&(allyears.sex=='M'),]
maleNameCounts = df.groupby(['Year', 'Name']).size().nlargest(10).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
maleNameCounts
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. But this does not help since it just gives a grouping of year and names.
I am looking for top10 names by counts for each year. 
Thank you again for looking into this.

Comment: @Satish I have updated the code now.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir.Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please upvote and mark this question as resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

Add a column with counts

```
df["name_count"] = df[name].map(df.name.value_counts())
```

Optional to remove duplicates

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(["name"])
```

Sort (by counts)

```
df = df.sort_values("name_count")
```

Note that this can all be tweaked were necessary.

Comment: Thank you. This is close, but not yet there:).
There 3 years in the data. 
I want top 10 names by count for each year. 
Your solution is helpful. I will try to build on that. 
But if you can think of a solution. Please do let me know.
Thank you again.